# Error in ModelSim, near "=": syntax error, unexpected '='. Syntax error found in the scope following 'Y'. Is there a missing '::'?

Tags: verilog

I'm making the master JK flipflop, and the errors came out like this:

```
** Error: (vlog-13069) C:/Windows/System32/ssy_1775_final.v(13): near "=": syntax error, unexpected '='.
** Error: C:/Windows/System32/ssy_1775_final.v(13): (vlog-13205) Syntax error found in the scope following 'Y'. Is there a missing '::'?
```

The code I made is as below:

```
    module JK_FlipFlop(J, K, clk, Y_BAR, Y, Q);
    input J, K, clk;
    output Y, Q;
    reg Y_BAR;
    wire Y, Q;

always@(posedge clk) 
assign Y_BAR = ~Y;
begin
if(J==0 && K==0) 
begin Y=Y; Y_BAR=Y_BAR; end
else if(J==0 && K==1) 
begin Y<=1'b0; Y_BAR<=1'b1; end
else if(J==1 && K==0) 
begin Y<=1'b1; Y_BAR<=1'b0; end
else if(J==1 && K==1) 
begin Y=Y_BAR; Y_BAR=Y; end
end

always@(negedge clk)
begin
if(Y==0 && Y_BAR==0)
 begin end
else if(Y==0 && Y_BAR==1)
  begin Q<=1'b0; end
else if(Y==1 && Y_BAR==0)
  begin Q<=1'b1; end
else if(Y==1 && Y_BAR==1)
  begin Q<=~Q; end
end

endmodule
```

I don't know why the error came out.

I pray that someone will spare me.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple errors in your port and signal declarations.  Since you make procedural assignments to all your outputs, they must all be declared as `reg`, not `wire`.  To reduce signal name duplication, thereby avoiding common errors like this, use ANSI style ports as shown below.

Another problem is that you should not use the `assign` keyword inside the `always` block.  The following code compiles without errors:

```
module JK_FlipFlop (
    input J, K, clk,
    output reg Y, Q, Y_BAR
);

always@(posedge clk) 
begin
    Y_BAR = ~Y;
    if(J==0 && K==0) 
    begin Y=Y; Y_BAR=Y_BAR; end
    else if(J==0 && K==1) 
    begin Y<=1'b0; Y_BAR<=1'b1; end
    else if(J==1 && K==0) 
    begin Y<=1'b1; Y_BAR<=1'b0; end
    else if(J==1 && K==1) 
    begin Y=Y_BAR; Y_BAR=Y; end
end

always@(negedge clk)
begin
    if(Y==0 && Y_BAR==0)
     begin end
    else if(Y==0 && Y_BAR==1)
      begin Q<=1'b0; end
    else if(Y==1 && Y_BAR==0)
      begin Q<=1'b1; end
    else if(Y==1 && Y_BAR==1)
      begin Q<=~Q; end
end

endmodule
```

---

Your code would be easier to understand if you improve the indentation.